# opencv installation error: installed in python 2 rther than in python 3.5

Tags: 16.04, python3, opencv

l'm under ubuntu 16.04, and python 3.5.2 l want to install opencv. I followed step by step the instructions in the following link :

http://cyaninfinite.com/tutorials/installing-opencv-in-ubuntu-for-python-3/

However , l'm supposed to run it in python3.5 (it's not working) but it is installed in python2 (it works)
what's wrong with my installation

**EDIT1**

```
python2
import cv2 # works but it's not supposed to work because l specified to install in for python3.5

python3.5
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

However it is supposed to work with python3.5

```
**EDIT2**
python3.5 --version
Python 3.5.2
python3 --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)

**EDIT3**
python3.5-config --includes
-I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include/python3.5m
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than *"(it's not working)"*

Comment: @steeldriver, please see my update

Comment: Thanks - it might help to include `python3 --version` and `python3.5 --version`. BTW did you follow the **Troubleshooting ImportError: No module named ‘cv2’** section at the bottom of the guide that you linked?

Comment: l updated  my post. @steeldriver no l didn't how can l do that ?

Comment: Maybe the installer found Anaconda 3.6.0 in your PYTHONPATH and either installed cv2 there - or got confused and gave up?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the output from `python3.5-config --includes`

Comment: @sempaiscuba,  see my updates

Comment: @steeldriver, if it has found ancaocnda 3.6.0  opencv would have worked on python3.6

Comment: Try deleting everything in your `build` directory and then recompiling the makefile.